# File not displaying in sharepoint 2010 library all items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

> Hi, I have a document library in sharepoint 2010 foundation.when i have uploaded a file into a document library from browser, it is showing a message"uploaded successfully" but it is not showing in document library all items.but when am open the site in IE and in library tab am clicking in file explorer button, in that file explorer the doc file is there.but in site -> doc library all items the file is not displaying. Am the administrator the site.

Comment: Do you have permission to view this file? ExplorerView tends to ignore permission set by Workflows

Comment: yes, am the administrator. prev it works fine. but now it is not working

Comment: Maybe file located in folder?

Answer (score 0):

If your library has versioning with minor versions enabled, uploaded files will be drafts. It may be the sort of confusing case that even as administrator, you do not have the rights to see drafts.

In the Library Settings, open the Versioning settings menu. Try setting the Draft Item Security option to all with read or edit permissions. Ensure that you own the respective rights (personally or as a member of an appropriate group).

Changing this option solved the problem for me. However, I experienced this setting as being kind of weird: Setting the option back to its former state (in which I did not see the documents) did not make the documents disappear again.